# Append new keypair to JSON file with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

I've read almost every question I can find on SO with the same general premise and I've gotten close three different times, but I just can't make this work.

Given a JSON file called `parameters.json` with keypairs like so; (shortened for sharing purposes)

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo1",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo2",  
    "ParameterValue": "Bar2"
  }
]
```

I want to add another keypair, say

```
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo3",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar3"
  }
```

So I end up with a file like

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo1",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo2",  
    "ParameterValue": "Bar2"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo3",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar3"
  }
]
```

## Use Case & Attempts

I'm writing a bash script that copies and updates parameter files for AWS - this is where the keypairs come in. We have a new keypair that needs to be added to any existing files when they're copied. I can get the if/then done fine, it's physically adding the new keypair that is stumping me.

With a ton of googling I ended up with this clunky workaround, which I don't really understand and, while it generates the keypair just fine, doesn't add it back into parameters.json

```
item='{"ParameterKey": "RTSMSnapshotID"}'

jq --argjson item "$item" '$item + {"ParameterValue": ""}' parameters.json
```

I get the keypair printed back to me correctly on the command line, so I figure add `| sponge parameters.json` but that then gives me an empty file.

I also considered a sed workaround that trimmed the last line of the file and then appended the new keypair (and EOF) but of course sed doesn't play well with newlines and I can't get it to work.

I'm open to solutions that use anything in bash and anything in jq. I am still a bash/jq noob so detailed explanations are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of using `argjson` is right, but the syntax is as below on `jq-1.5`

```
jq --argjson obj '{ "ParameterKey": "Foo3", "ParameterValue": "Bar3" }' '. + [$obj]' < json 
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo1",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar1"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo2",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar2"
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Foo3",
    "ParameterValue": "Bar3"
  }
]
```

Check the [jq-documentation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for more information about the `+` and `+=` operators.

Am not aware of ways to do this in `jq` itself, but you can use a neat `bash` trick to do this,

```
jq --argjson obj '{ "ParameterKey": "Foo3", "ParameterValue": "Bar3" }' '. + [$obj]' < json > temp && mv temp json
```

Comment: This does add the new keypair as expected (thanks!), but prints the output to the command line. How do I pipe it back into `parameters.json`?

Comment: Just in case anyone comes along needing to use this - turns out you can add `| sponge parameters.json` if you have the tools installed for an easy workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one file with a JSON array (say parameters.json), and one or more additional files (say file*.json) with JSON entities that you want to append to the array in the first file, and if you want to overwrite the first file, here's a rather sly solution, which however requires jq 1.5 or later:

```
$ jq 'reduce inputs as $in (.; . + [$in])' parameters.json file*.json |
    sponge parameters.json
```

Note that using this approach, each top-level JSON entity in each of the auxiliary files will be appended to the array separately.

What makes this a bit crafty is that `inputs` is being used here without the -n option.

Since you mentioned `bash`, please note that if any of the "file*.json" sources is a process, you could use `<( ... )` rather than specifying a filename, e.g.:

```
$ jq 'reduce inputs as $in (.; . + [$in])' parameters.json <(curl -Ss ...) |
    sponge parameters.json
```

If you don't have `sponge`, then you can use the idiom:

```
jq ..... > OUT && mv IN OUT
```

Comment: I specifically needed a solution with no intermediary files as this process happens in Jenkins and as soon as files are involved it clutters workspaces or requires git checkouts. I am upvoting however as I appreciate the answer; might be useful to someone else with a different use case.

Comment: @Alex Can you use <( ... ) ?