# Add new key to json array using jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Why is the accepted answer in "[Append new keypair to JSON file with jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42817889/append-new-keypair-to-json-file-with-jq)" not working in my case?

I have a file `newFile.json` which contains:

```
[ { "groupId": 11, "lowerThreshold": 33, "target": { "alarm_id": 22 },
"thresholdPeriod": 3, "upperThreshold": 44 }, { "groupId": 31,
"lowerThreshold": 33, "target": { "alarm_id": 122 },
"thresholdPeriod": 3, "upperThreshold": 44 } ]
```

I want to insert another value to the array in ruleGroup.json which has:

```
{ "groupId": "0", "target": { "alarm_id": "69" }, "upperThreshold":
"20", "lowerThreshold": "10", "thresholdPeriod": "5" }
```

As per the accepted answer, I saved `ruleGroup.json` to `obj`.

When I run

```
jq --argjson obj '$obj' '. + [$obj]' < newFile.json
```

it returns:

```
[ "{\n \"groupId\": \"0\",\n \"target\": {\n \"alarm_id\": \"69\"\n
},\n \"upperThreshold\": \"20\",\n \"lowerThreshold\": \"10\",\n
\"thresholdPeriod\": \"5\"\n}" ]
```

Which is similar to the `$obj` value itself. It didn't create the expected result which was to append this value to the array:

```
[ { "groupId": 11, "lowerThreshold": 33, "target": { "alarm_id": 22 },
"thresholdPeriod": 3, "upperThreshold": 44 }, { "groupId": 31,
"lowerThreshold": 33, "target": { "alarm_id": 122 },
"thresholdPeriod": 3, "upperThreshold": 44 }, { "groupId": "0",
"target": { "alarm_id": "69" }, "upperThreshold": "20",
"lowerThreshold": "10", "thresholdPeriod": "5" } ]
```

Comment: how did you try? It's working fine for me

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Please read "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)"
and "[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/)". Failing to format correctly slows answers and often discourages them entirely. We expect you to put in the effort to create well asked questions since you're asking us to help you. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

If the object you want to add is in a file, you should be using `--slurpfile` instead of trying to read it into a shell variable and then pass that to `jq`:

```
$ jq --slurpfile obj ruleGroup.json '. + $obj' newFile.json 
[
  {
    "groupId": 11,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 22
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  },
  {
    "groupId": 31,
    "lowerThreshold": 33,
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": 122
    },
    "thresholdPeriod": 3,
    "upperThreshold": 44
  },
  {
    "groupId": "0",
    "target": {
      "alarm_id": "69"
    },
    "upperThreshold": "20",
    "lowerThreshold": "10",
    "thresholdPeriod": "5"
  }
]
```